# Array with No Upper Boundaries in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have been attempting to wrap my head around an idea that I am certain is possible, I just am not sure if I am going about it in the right way. My intention is to create an array and then fill it with as many values as the user wants. However my goal is to not use any defined value per se. I would like to be able to continue increasing it the amount of values it can contain indefinitely.

This is the test code I have been using to try and figure this out:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
        int i;
        int Up;
        int Ary[0];

        printf("Please enter the number of integers you want to input: ");
        scanf("%d", &Up);
        for(i = 0; i < Up; i++)
        {
                printf("Please enter a number: ");
                Ary[i] = (int) malloc(sizeof(int));
                scanf("%d", &Ary[i]);
        }
        for(i = 0; i < Up; i++)
        {
                printf("%d ", Ary[i]);
                if(i % 10 == 0)
                {
                        printf("\n");
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

This may be a poor way of attempting to figure this out and I may also be doing this is a completely wrong way; However I get a segmentation fault sometimes. If I use small values such as only entering 4 or 5 values it works fine, however if I enter 10 values it gives me a segmentation fault. If I enter 50 values, it lets me enter all 50 but gives me a segmentation fault after printing out the 41st value.

The code itself is simply a means to an end. Ultimately what I would like to know is how I can set up an array of anything that can have values added to it indefinitely while retaining previous values using dynamic memory allocation?

*PS. I hope this defines my question well enough, however if it does not I would like to refine my question so it is more clear. Please make a comment if this is unclear and why.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't going to work:

```
int Ary[0];
```

You've made an array with no elements; the only valid use of such an array is to take its address, but you can't index into it as you have done.

Instead, you should make a pointer to what will later be allocated as an array:

```
int *Ary;
```

Then when you know how many integers you want:

```
Ary = malloc(Up * sizeof(int));
```

Now you can do `Ary[index]` for any index from 0 to (Up-1).  If you later want to enlarge the array, you can use `realloc()` (many tutorials online for that).

Comment: How would I do this, if lets say I were to add 12 integers and then come back later in the program and decide I wanted to add a 13th? However I did not specify 13 to start because I only needed 12 at the time.

Comment: I have honestly spent the last few hours searching, perhaps the way I am searching for this is wrong, but I was getting nowhere fast with the information I needed.

Comment: @Arrowkill: now that you know you need to use `realloc()` you should be able to figure it out.  If you get stuck, ask a new question about `realloc()`.

Comment: `int Ary[0];` is not only “not going to work,” it's not going to compile either! ISO 9899:2011 §6.7.6.3 *Array declarators* ¶1 (emphasis mine): “[...] the `[` and `]` may delimit an expression [...] the expression shall have an integer type. [...] **it shall have a value greater than zero.** [...]”

Comment: @FUZxxl: Just because the C standard disallows zero-length arrays does not mean they will not compile.  In fact, GCC explicitly allows them as a (sometimes useful, but not in the OP's context) extension: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: @JohnZwinck If you compile Standard C and not GNU C, they will not compile. This proprietary compiler extension is not interesting to me.

Comment: @FUZxxl: As you know, regular people who are learning C usually don't choose any special compiler options (otherwise we'd see a lot more use of `-Wall`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic allocation, what you are doing right now is static allocation, you need to learn how to use `malloc` and `free`.

So keep in mind that what you want to do is not "efficient" but can definitely be done as a learning exercise to learn how to make such a container.

What you need to do is allocate the amount of memory needed to contain the amount of values currently in your array +1 more value every time you want to "add" a new value to your array, for example: `malloc(sizeof(int)*(<current_number_of_values>+1))`.

I say "add" in quotes because what you will have to do is actually allocate memory for a brand new array every time and copy over your old values plus the new value the user enters and then `free` your old array to avoid memory leaks.

There are STL containers that do this internally but much more efficiently but I assume you are doing this to learn and not use your own containers for anything serious.

Comment: You would be correct, to be precise I am testing this before I tear apart some already written code and redesign it to the new specifications for my class.